# IOS Flutter problem Codemagic install close up immediately

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase

I have a problem when i launch my flutter app after i make a build using codemagic , the application built successfully but then , when i try it on an ios device the app shows me white screen then close up itself what can i do to fix this !

i tried several things the app is launch on android perfectly non on ios
i dont have macbook also
my app use firebase i've added the GoogleService.plist to Runner folder with no result
im using codemagic to build and publish to appstore
i cant use xcode but if you have an idea please share it with me

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please share your config of th app, on code magic or the permissions you're giving on apple console, it could've been happening so may things causing the crash, do you have any crash reporting service?

Comment: This is happening with me and with a friend too. It's only happens on certains device models like iPhone 8 and iPhone 11. Deliverying app manually from xcode fix the issue.